# Capture Pin property window in Directshow c#

Tags: c#, directshow

I'd like to grab some samples from a video stream with a sample grabber from a capture device. This works well for the default 640*480 resolution. I've seen a few examples codes (for some reason I cant seem to open these thats why I'm asking) where it was possible to change the properties of the capture pin when selecting a capture device in a property window and I'd like to replicate this aswell. Could anyone give some advice concerning this? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ask the pin for IAMStreamConfig interface, it will allow you to list available video modes and select desired one. You can test it in [GraphEditPlus](http://www.infognition.com/GraphEditPlus/) by right clicking the capture pin and selecting IAMStreamConfig::GetStreamCaps or IAMStreamConfig::SetFormat.

Comment: Cool thank you I managed to solve it using this. Another question that came up, I'd like to use 4 veho vms-004d microscopes for showing video streams + image capturing. Now it works flawlessly for 2 devices but I get blank screen in both VS and in GraphEditPlus for the other 2 and GE freezes frequently with all 4 connected,so its probably not a coding error . Any idea if thers a limit to how many capture devices can be present at the same time or some other thing that might cause this? All 4 devices are recognised by windows.

Comment: I have run 8 capture devices at once from a single program. Unfortunately, my program couldn't keep up with the data streams for overnight so caused some of the capture sources to go offline. In my case, this was a different capture devices than what you are using (mine were all Hauppauge HD-PVR's).

Comment: How were your devices arranged? Were they connected to a single computer or was it a server/client setup with multiple pc's? These are simple usb devices and I have the feeling that 2 simultaneous streams somehow eat up the entire usb bandwidth.

Comment: I have managed to solve that one aswell. Apparently each device uses around 40% of the usb controllers bandwidth ,so have to use 2 separate usb controllers for this and then it works fine.